# How to change ActionOverflow position in a toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

[image: my toolbar]

In my image above, am using a toolbar as my action bar. in this toolbar I have a textview which contain the name **president** and i have a tablayout which contain 3 tabs(**item1,item2,item3**)

when i inflate my menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method, my ActionOverflow(**the three white dots**) is appearing **below my president textview** and i would like to appear **on the far right of president textview. this is affecting my tablayout width because it can't match parent(toolbar) which fills the screen width**.

How can i achive my objective?

**my activity xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/mainActivityBar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="President"
            android:id="@+id/appname_1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            style="@style/myCustomTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appname_1"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/appname_1"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**my syles**

```
<style name="mainActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>

</style>

<style name="myCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. This is working correctly in my case.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Add this in your gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
}
```

v21/styles

```
<resources>>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

styles

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Dimens

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="appbar_padding_top">8dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

---

Add this to your Manifest

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Comment: how will i then use FloatingActionButton in my activity? will i change the way i call toolbar and tablayout since they are now in AppBarLayout?

Comment: Remove FloatingActionButton if you dont need it.  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);  TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

Comment: am facing an errors on styles. **cannot resolve style** @style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay

Comment: can you please provide for me the styles and dimension that you have used?

Comment: i have never used this coordinator layout. and now my viewpager is occupying the entire screen! men how will i align it at the bottom of appbar

Comment: Edit your question with what you have you have done so far

Comment: first of all, my action overflow isn't changing its position. second, i am using margin to force my viewpager be at the bottom of appbar. is there a better way to align it at bottom because even when i use `alyout_gravity=bottom` it's not working.

Comment: can you please help me get out of this mess. i have copied your code exactly. and  my action overflow **still isn't changing it position!**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95701/discussion-between-gikarasojo-kinene-and-sunny).